# Re-cert after upgrading Apache + OpenSSL

Tags: apache-2.4, openssl

This is probably a captain noobenstein question but I cannot figure out how to google this issue for an answer.

I've just upgraded from Apache 2.4.10 w/ OpenSSL 1.0.1j to Apache 2.4.18 w/ OpenSSL 1.0.2e

Do I need to regenerate my SSL files and get re-validated with my certificate authority?

If not, then why?

---

FWIW

My previous `.key` and `.csr` files were created like this:

```
openssl.exe genrsa -out {The_FQDN}.key 2048
openssl.exe req -new -sha256 -key {The_FQDN}.key -out {The_FQDN}.csr
```

Comment: No, because your existing certificate has not expired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The certificate validation process contains four basic steps.

1. Generate a request
2. Generate a key (the .key file in your apache config)
3. Submit the request to a CA for validation
4. Receive a certificate (the .cer or .crt in your apache config)

Since these steps are time sensitive - *the request which was submitted is still the request which was validated* - there is no reason to go through the validation process again.

In other words your certificate / key binding is already made and there is no reason to revise it. This does assume that you still have the same certificate and key as previously used.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I do have the same certificate and key. I guess my main concern was whether or not the newer OpenSSL does anything different when creating the `.key` and `.csr` file which could cause incompatibilities; assuming I use the same parameters as before.

Comment: If you would like, you can check out my edit to see the exact command I used during my Apache 2.4.10 install.